# subsetting and combining/matching data

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns... Date, Hour, Loc, Value.

What I'd like to do with the data is come up with summary statistic for each unique Date/hour/loc.  This seems to be easy since I can do

```
x <- subset(my.df[,4], 
            my.df[,2]==(some parameter) & my.df[,3]==(another parameter)
           )
```

and then get whatever summary statistics I want from x.  However the tricky part is that I also want to get summary statistics from each of the differences of the aforementioned values.  So for instance I want to take the difference of value when `loc=1` from `value` when `loc=2` with `hour=1` but there may or may not be missing days within either of the locs.  One idea I had which probably will work is to reshape `my.df` to be wider twice.  Firstly make it wide with `timevar=loc` and then reshape that with `timevar=hour` so that I'll have wide.df with columns Date, value.1.1, value.1.2 etc where the first integer is the loc and the second integer is the hour and each row is a unique date.

Is there a more straight forward to do this that won't involve 20 minutes of reshaping (the initial df is about 9493401 rows with 4 variables and then I stretch it out to 720 rows with 14857 columns?
@Brandon: Here's the str output.  I haven't tried your suggestions yet though.

```
        'data.frame':   9493401 obs. of  4 variables:
    $ Loc  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ Date: POSIXct, format: "2010-10-29" "2010-10-29" ...
    $ Hour     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
    $ Value   : num  7.63 4.07 4.9 1.61 0.34 -5.23 2.11 2.39 7.2 4.41 ...
```

Comment: Can you show us str(my.df)?

Comment: From what you've shown us, dcast() will work. You'll need to play around with the formula a bit until you get it to do what you want. Unless of course, you create a toy example of what you expect to see as rows and columns.

Comment: please don't forget to vote and accept answers as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). I see you have asked five questions and not accepted a single answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `dcast` from `reshape2` which seems to be pretty snappy in this regard:

```
library(reshape2)
dat <- data.frame(date=sample(1:100,9493401,replace=TRUE),
                  hour=rep(1:24,1000000)[1:9493401],
                  loc=rep(letters[1:9],1054823)[1:9493401],
                  value=rnorm(9493401))     

dcast(dat,date + hour ~ loc)
```

You can also do things like counts of loc/hour

```
dcast(dat, date + hour ~ loc*hour)
```

You'll need to provide more information if you want an answer that's specific to your case.

Comment: I invested the time to ditch using reshape and went to reshape2 which is paying dividends.  Thanks.